# Undefined is not an object in after effects extendscript

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I have a script where i upload lot of aeps and merge them

I am using the following code

```js
var aepFile = "local location of aep";
var importOpts = new ImportOptions(File(aepFile));
var aeFolder = app.project.importFile(importOpts);

for (var n = 1; n <= aeFolder.numItems; n++) {
        app.layers.add(aeFolder.item(n));
}
```

The problem is at some point of time the error shows that undefined is not an object
it is referencing the aeFolder variable I checked , it is imported , but we can't get the data right . Maybe it's not synchronous ? No , because it runs perfectly the next time , Please help

Edit: 
it points out that aeFolder is undefined , the index are 1 based, not 0 based.

Yes I can reproduce the error in a different project.

Might this happen if the RAM is low?

Answer (score 1):

There are several points where this could go wrong.

1. What is importOpts?
2. Has `aeFolder.numItems` 0 based or 1 based index?
3. Can you reproduce the error in a separate project?

```js
var aeFolder = app.project.importFile(importOpts);

for (var n = 1; n <= aeFolder.numItems; n++) {
        app.layers.add(aeFolder.item(n));
}
```

Can you please provide an example project for us to test it. 
Or more context to reproduce this error